# How to convert 2 D array to 1 D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can i convert an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
)
```

to

```
Array
    (
        A
        B
        C
        D
        E
        F
    )
```

I tried using foreach key value and assigning value to new array , but even new array will be in 2D form

Comment: This question makes no sense. You'll always have keys for your array.

Comment: The basic mistake here is assuming this array as 2-dimensional.

Comment: The closest thing to what you want would be a String, I guess. So just `implode('', $array)` the array. Which you could still access with $string[0] => A, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look into what 2D arrays are:

1D array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
)
```

1D associative array:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => A
    [bar] => B
    [moreFoo] => C
    [someElse] => D
)
```

2D array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
        [3] => D
        [4] => E
        [5] => F
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
        [3] => D
        [4] => E
        [5] => F
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
        [3] => D
        [4] => E
        [5] => F
    )
)
```

2D associative array:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
    (
        [foo] => A
        [bar] => B
        [moreFoo] => C
        [someElse] => D
    )
    [name] => Array
    (
        [foo] => A
        [bar] => B
        [moreFoo] => C
        [someElse] => D
    )
    [thirdElement] => Array
    (
        [foo] => A
        [bar] => B
        [moreFoo] => C
        [someElse] => D
    )
)
```

Comment: There is not actual php code answer here, just an explanation of the various array types.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a 2d array to start with. It is a 1d array... all arrays in PHP comprise key/value pairs. so

```
array('A','B')
```

is a 1d array with values A and B, to which keys are automatically assigned (0 and 1) as their offset position in that array.

A 2d array would be something like

```
array( array('A','B')
       array('C','D')
     )
```

Comment: The [0],[1], ... shown are keys or indexes, not values. They are in the same first dimension. 
http://ideone.com/5eVJM1

Comment: @PaulH - Do I say anywhere in this answer that 0 and 1 are values? I specifically say that they are keys: `to which keys are automatically assigned (0 and 1)`

Comment: What you say is completely right. I gave it a +1. I just wanted to add some information for a novice, like GoodSp33d back in 2012

Comment: @PaulH Lol Cant believe I asked this question. I cannot delete it also :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense... If you have that "flat" array, how are you gonna address, for example the 3rd element of it?

Also as @Shiplu mentioned in the comment, the array you use as an example is already a 1-d array, 2-d's array is in the form of

```
$array['level1']['level2'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

All arrays in php have keys, whether you assign them or not when you create the array. The index starts at 0, so you would access A for example using 0, B using 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to convert an **unsorted indexed array** something similar to:

```
array (
    [2] => A,
    [5] => B,
    [8] => C,
    ["x"] => D,
    ["v"] => E,
    [0] => F
);
```

to

```
array (
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
);
```

If it is the case then use the **[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)** function.

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```